# how to find the dimension of $ W^{\perp}$?

Tags: inner-products

For $ M_n( \mathbb{C})$ ,the vector space  of $all  \ n \times  n$  complex matrices  over $\mathbb{C}$

Given that $W =\{ x \in M_n( \mathbb{C}| trace(X) =0\}$ is a subspace of $ M_n( \mathbb{C})$ and $W ^{\perp}$ consists of sacalar matrices that is  if $tr(AX) = 0$ for all $x \in  M_n( \mathbb{C})$  with $trX =0$ ,then $A= \lambda I$ for some scalars $\lambda$   . Find  the dimension of

$1)$$ W$

$2)$$W^{\perp}$

## My attempts :

i know  that  dimension of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$  is  $2n^2.$  now  $trace A =a_{11} +a_{22} +a_{33} +......+a_{nn}=0$

so the dimension of $W = 2n^2 -1$

here  im confusion about that how to find  the dimension of $ W^{\perp}$?

any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks u

Comment: The dimension is related to the underlying field. Here we are considering $\mathrm M_n(\mathbb C)$, so the dimension is actually dimension over $\mathbb C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dimension of $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is $n^2$, not $2n^2$. And anyway, if you know how to find the dimension of $W$ then the dimension of $W^{\perp}$ is the codimension of $W$, which means $dim(M_n(\mathbb{C}))-dim(W)$.

Comment: thanks @ Marks..